# Как записать в переменную канал или роль?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Идея:**

> Я хочу сделать 1 команду что бы она закрывала 3-ом(существующим) разным ролям право на общение в 3-ох разных каналах(текстовых, существующих).

Вот к примеру тут я создаю канал и записываю его в переменную, а потом меняю права:

```
channel = await integration.guild.create_voice_channel(f"{integration.user.name}'s voice ", category=category)
await channel.set_permissions(integration.user, overwrite=overwrite)
```

А как записать в переменную существующий канал или роль что бы потом у него изменять права и тд?

**Подскажите как это сделать?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете просто заново получить объект канала

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(channel.id)
```

Хотя, я не уверен, что это требуется. На всякий случай проверьте меняется ли значение свойства у текущего объекта канала после выполнения метода

```py
await channel.set_permissions()
```

Comment: Спасибо! А что бы засунуть в переменную роль нужно использовать bot.get_role()?

Comment: @Lipkou `guild.get_role()` или `discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=id_роли)`

Comment: выбивает ошибку: `roles = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=1023551361222180915)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles`

Comment: @Lipkou объект сервера получите сначала

Comment: а из-за чего может произойти ошибка когда пишу `guild = bot.get_guild(720618721244348428)` в  `guild` записывается значение `None`?

Comment: 3 варианта — либо неправильно указан id, либо бот не стоит на этом сервере, либо этого сервера нет в кеше, тогда следует использовать `guild = await bot.fetch_guild(id)`